# How can I ask someone to move closer to someone else on a couch so I can sit down?

Tags: phrasal-verbs

Is there a phrasal verb with this meaning:
Let's say that there are two people sitting on a couch there's some space between them and there's also some space between one of the people and the edge of the couch how to do I ask that person to move closer to the other person so that there is enough space for me to sit on the couch by using a phrasal verb?

Comment: How about “scoot over”?

Comment: Very informally, to a good friend "Shove, love." More commonly just "could you move across please"

Comment: NB _Scoot over_ is mainly American. _Hutch up_ is another possibility.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're speaking to people you don't know very well, you'd probably say, "Excuse me, could you move over a little to make room for me to sit here?"

If you're speaking to friends or family, you might, as SegNerd says in a comment, say, "Scoot over."

Answer (score 0):

"Could we squeeze up, please" doesn't require the same level of familiarity as "Shove up"